# MySQL Select a particular data from a row with multiple value

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure whether this has been asked or not. I have a database where one of the columns has multiple data in a single row. I wonder what should I do if want to see the data with a certain value from those rows.

For example, I want to see the table for the BUILDINGS group only. When I tried to do this:

```
SELECT **
WHERE groups='BUILDINGS'
```

there will be no data shown.

What I expect is something like this:

```
node name   x   y   z   max   groups
   336     ... ... ...  ...    ... 
   340     ... ... ...  ...    ... 
   342     ... ... ...  ...    ...
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOTZe.png)

thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share what your picture has to do with "no data shown". Also explain why you use `**`, because everyone normally uses only one `*` when using SQL.   Actually MySQL gives an error when using `**`, something like: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;....for the right syntax to use near '*.......`

Comment: @Luuk `no data shown` I'm guessing  it might be: With the query that the OP is using it will result in empty set, so there is no data shown. @Yohannes Cahyadi you should search some basic `MySQL`  there is no `SELECT` without `FROM`. This might help for a start: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Comment: Ah, the screen image was showing the "expected output".....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT * from '{your table name}'
WHERE groups like '%BUILDINGS%'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from <your table Name> where groups like '%BUILDINGS%';
```

Comment: Glad that it worked